# unwanted \x{d} when opening a file

Tags: perl, split

I have a .conf file where a list of tests to execute are written in a line, with different scenarios per test.
It looks like this :

```
scenario1,scenario2
scenario1,scenario2,scenario3
scenario1
```

In my code I open the file :

```
sub get_tests {
my $nb_tests = 0;
my @length_tests;
my @lists_scenarios;
my @current_list; 
my $current_length; 

# Open the conf file with all the tests to execute
my $filename = $folder_lists_scenarios.$scenario_list.".conf";
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename) or die $!;
# open my $fh, "<", $folder_lists_scenarios.$scenario_list.".conf" or die $!;


# Get all the scenarios
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;                                 # delete carrier return
    $nb_tests++;                                # increment number of tests
    @current_list = split(/,/, $row);           # separate the test into scenarios
    $current_length = @current_list;            # get the number of scenarios in the test
    push @length_tests, $current_length;        # store the number of scenarios
    push @lists_scenarios, [@current_list];     # store the list of scenarios of the test
}

# Close the file
close $fh;


return ($nb_tests, \@length_tests, \@lists_scenarios);
```

}

My problem is that I use these strings to open files that have the name of the strings :

```
sub open_txt {
# Open a txt file and return then content in an array
my $filename = "folder_with_scenarios/".$_[0]."/content.txt";
my @lines;
my $temp;

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename'. Please check if the file name is correct or in the good repertory.";

my $cnt_line = 0;
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
    chomp $row;
    $cnt_line++;
    if ( length($row) > 1 ) { # if the line is not empty
        $temp = length($row);
        push @lines, $row 
    } 
}

# If the file is not empty
if ($cnt_line > 0) {
    return ($cnt_line, @lines);

# If the file is empty
} else {
    die "[ERROR]     The file $filename is empty\n";
}
```

}

And when I do this, the first scenarios of the line work well but the last of the line makes an error :

```
Uncaught exception from user code:
/content.txt'. Please check if the file name is correct or in the good repertory. at ./my_code.pl line 2219.
    main::open_txt('folder_with_scenarios/scenario2\x{d}/content') called at ./my_code.pl line 2588
```

Apparently I have a \x{d} at the end of my line string and I don't know how to get rid of it.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

SLP

Comment: `\x{d}` looks like a carriage return. You might want to `s/\r\n$//` instead of `chomp` (can't post an answer right now)

Comment: I also thought about carrier return but when I print the string it doesn't print any carrier return, it only generates a problem when I use the string to open a file....

Comment: Carriage returns don't really show when you try to print them (I mean `perl -E 'say "ab\r"'` doesn't "show" any carriage return, yet there is one). Did you try what I suggested and did it not work indeed? In your `while` loop, add `say join ",", map ord, $row =~ /./g;`, and see if it ends with 13.

Comment: I have tried it and it didn't work (syntax error). Are you sure about your command ?

Comment: Add `use feature 'say';` at the begining of your code (or replace `say` with `print "$_\n"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you are passing to `open_txt` ends with a Carriage Return.

You presumably read the value from a file that had Windows (CRLF) line endings on a non-Windows machine.

You presumably used `chomp` to remove the Line Feed, but left the Carriage Return in place.

If so, replace

```
chomp;
```

with

```
s/\s+\z//;
```